# Getting "Original error: Could not find a connected Android device" error when using Appium with webdriver/sikuli

Tags: android, eclipse, appium

Appium is running perfectly when try in separate project. But when I use with WebDriver/Sikuli getting the following exceptions,

**org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not find a connected Android device.)**

**My Code is:**

```
public class HelloAppium {
static AppiumDriver appiumDriver;
static WebDriver driver;
static AndroidDriver androidDriver;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {

    
    AppiumServerUtils aServer = new AppiumServerUtils();
    aServer.startServer();
    System.out.println("Started");
    
    setUp();
            
    WebElement ele =  androidDriver.findElement(By.id("com.android.device:id/editPin"));
    ele.click();
    ele.sendKeys("1111");
    ele.clear();
    
    ele.sendKeys("");
    androidDriver.hideKeyboard();
            
    aServer.stopServer();
    
}

private static void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities mDesiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    mDesiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
    mDesiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Moto X");
    mDesiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "net.android.device");
    mDesiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.android.launcher.Main");
    mDesiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_WAIT_ACTIVITY, "com.android.tools.remotecontrol.dialogs.Authentication");
    
    mDesiredCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4.4");
    
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), mDesiredCapabilities);
    androidDriver = (AndroidDriver)driver;
    appiumDriver = (AppiumDriver)driver;
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    androidDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    appiumDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
}
```

}

**CommandLine code to start Appium is,**

```
public class AppiumServerUtils {

public  void startServer(){
    CommandLine command = new CommandLine("cmd");
    command.addArgument("/c",false);
    command.addArgument("F:\\Softwares\\Selenium\\Appium\\AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1\\Appium\\node.exe",false);
    command.addArgument("F:\\Softwares\\Selenium\\Appium\\AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\bin\\appium.js", false);
    command.addArgument("--address",false);
    
    command.addArgument("127.0.0.1",false);
    command.addArgument("--port",false);
    command.addArgument("4723",false);
    command.addArgument("--bootstrap-port",false);
    command.addArgument("4724",false);
    command.addArgument("--selendroid-port",false);
    command.addArgument("8082",false); 
    command.addArgument("--no-reset",false);
    command.addArgument("--local-timezone",false);
    command.addArgument("--log",false);
    command.addArgument("F:\\Softwares\\Selenium\\Appium\\appiumServerLogs.txt",false);
    DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
    executor.setExitValue(1);


    InputStream is = new InputStream() {
        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return 0;
        }
    };

    try{
        //code for looking Appium server logs
        //executor.getStreamHandler().setProcessOutputStream(is);
        
        executor.execute(command, resultHandler);
        
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
            if(new File("F:\\Softwares\\Selenium\\Appium\\appiumServerLogs.txt").length()!=0){
                System.out.println("file size is not Zero ");
                break;
            }
                            
            System.out.println("file size is Zero ");
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            
        }

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public  void stopServer(){

    CommandLine command = new CommandLine("cmd");
    command.addArgument("/c");
    command.addArgument("taskkill");
    command.addArgument("/F");
    command.addArgument("/IM");
    command.addArgument("node.exe");

    DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
    executor.setExitValue(1);

    try {
        executor.execute(command, resultHandler);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

**Logs:**

> [36minfo[39m: [37m-->[39m [37mPOST[39m [37m/wd/hub/session[39m [90m{"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Moto X","appActivity":"com.android.launcher.Main","appWaitActivity":"com.android.tools.remotecontrol.dialogs.Authentication","appPackage":"net.android.device","version":"4.4.4"}}[39m [36minfo[39m: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : version [36minfo[39m: [debug] Didn't get app but did get Android package, will attempt to launch it on the device [36minfo[39m: [debug] Creating new appium session adee76d7-4d68-46a7-96d2-ae617d5a900d [36minfo[39m: Starting android appium [36minfo[39m: [debug] Using fast reset? false [36minfo[39m: [debug] Preparing device for session [36minfo[39m: [debug] Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on the device [36minfo[39m: [debug] Checking whether adb is present [36minfo[39m: [debug] Using adb from D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe [36minfo[39m: Retrieving device [36minfo[39m: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" kill-server [31merror[39m: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway [36minfo[39m: [debug] Getting connected devices... [36minfo[39m: [debug] executing: "D:\Saravanan\Softwares\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices [36minfo[39m: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop... [33mwarn[39m: UiAutomator did not shut down fast enough, calling it gone [31merror[39m: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Could not find a connected Android device. [36minfo[39m: [debug] Cleaning up android objects [36minfo[39m: [debug] Cleaning up appium session [36minfo[39m: [debug] Error: Could not find a connected Android device.
> at ADB.getDevicesWithRetry (F:\Softwares\Selenium\Appium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:612:15)
> at androidCommon.prepareActiveDevice (F:\Softwares\Selenium\Appium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:387:12)
> at null. (F:\Softwares\Selenium\Appium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:325:26)
> at F:\Softwares\Selenium\Appium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:610:21
> at F:\Softwares\Selenium\Appium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:249:17
> at iterate (F:\Softwares\Selenium\Appium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:149:13)
> at F:\Softwares\Selenium\Appium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:160:25
> at F:\Softwares\Selenium\Appium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:251:21
> at F:\Softwares\Selenium\Appium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:615:34
> at androidCommon.prepareEmulator (F:\Softwares\Selenium\Appium\AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:377:5) [36minfo[39m: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not find a connected Android device.)","origValue":"Could not find a connected Android device."},"sessionId":null} [36minfo[39m: [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session [39m[31m500[39m[90m 27317.283 ms - 206[39m [90m[39m Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not find a connected Android device.) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 27.41 seconds Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50' System info: host: 'Saravanan-PC', ip: '192.168.101.22', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_45' Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:180)    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:153)  at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:109)     at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:40)    at com.helloappium.HelloAppium.setUp(HelloAppium.java:134)  at com.helloappium.HelloAppium.main(HelloAppium.java:49)

Could anyone help & any suggestion to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This looks strange for me that your `APP_PACKAGE "net.android.device"` and `APP_ACTIVITY "com.android.launcher.Main"` point on the different packages.

Usually this defined as following

```
APP_PACKAGE  com.example.simpleaapp
APP_ACTIVITY com.example.simpleaapp.MyActivity
```

Comment: in our app, modified package name in AndroidManifest.xml. Its an optional u can change or not change

Comment: However this is also shown in the log - different packages